# Make a GET request to a local file in Google App Engine using Ajax

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine

I'd like to run a function server side using a Python file on my Google App Engine application with this Ajax call.

```
function test(){
  request = $.ajax({
    url: "test.py?some_vars...",
    type: "get",
  });
  request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

When I run test() the console logs a 404 error, "test.py not found". I've also tried "localhost:8080/test.py" locally and "http://APP.appspot.com/test.py" on the actual server.

I get a response when I try an external file like "http://graph.facebook.com/steve", but I can't get anything from local files.

Here is my app.yaml

```
application: APP
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /images
  static_dir: images 

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /.*
  script: apprtc.app
  secure: always

- url: /python
  script: test.app

inbound_services:
- channel_presence

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: What's your code on the server side?

Comment: I haven't written it yet, but that shouldn't matter since the client doesn't even see the file.

Comment: If you haven't written the code on the server side (test.py) then how could the server return anything but a 404 ?  If you have written test.py normally on appengine you wouldn't actually map the url like that.  Appengine is not old school cgi.

Comment: I told it to print a string, but I didn't enter the code that I intend to place in it.

Comment: Besides I tried html files and I still didn't get a response.

Comment: Show us your app.yaml, have you static handlers or request handlers setup ?  Without seeing that everything is just a guess.

Comment: `application: APP
version: 1
runtime: python27
threadsafe: true
api_version: 1

handlers:

- url: /images
  static_dir: images 

- url: /js
  static_dir: js

- url: /css
  static_dir: css

- url: /.*
  script: apprtc.app
  secure: always
  
- url: /python
  script: test.app
  
inbound_services:
- channel_presence

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
`

Comment: Is there anyway I can make that more organized?

Comment: Edit the question and paste the app.yaml there.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what part of this question appears unclear, useless, or lacking of research?

Comment: Was useful for me, thx for posting your issue!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a handler in app.yaml that maps to your test.py.

Comment: Should this suffice "- url: /python
  script: test.app"?

Comment: yup as long as you change the url in your ajax call to "/python?some_vars..."

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a route that looks something like...

```
- url: /test.py
  script: test.app
```